# Creating a .dll file in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, file, dll

I had created a project which is C# console application project for which I need to call this project dll in another windows application project. I had built the project in visual studio 2010 and checked for `.dll` file in bin\debug folder, but it is not created.

But a manifest file and `.exe` file havebeen created. Please help me out how to create the `.dll` in this case?

Comment: you just create class library project instead of console

Comment: one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771066/how-do-i-compile-c-sharp-code-as-a-library-instead-of-an-executable two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project use search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile C# code as a library instead of an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771066/how-do-i-compile-c-sharp-code-as-a-library-instead-of-an-executable)

Answer (score 66):

You need to make a class library and not a Console Application.  The console application is translated into an `.exe` whereas the class library will then be compiled into a `dll` which you can reference in your windows project.

- Right click on your Console Application -> Properties -> Change the Output type to Class Library

[image]

Answer (score 29):

To create a DLL File, click on New project, then select Class Library.

Enter your code into the class file that was automatically created for you and then click Build Solution from the Debug menu.

Now, look in your directory: ../debug/release/YOURDLL.dll

There it is! :)

P.S. DLL files cannot be run just like normal applciation (exe) files. You'll need to create a separate project (probably a win forms app) and then add your dll file to that project as a "Reference", you can do this by going to the Solution explorer, right clicking your project Name and selecting Add Reference then browsing to whereever you saved your dll file.

For more detail please click [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891258/how-to-create-a-dll-file)

Answer (score 7):

You need to change project settings. Right click your project, go to properites. In Application tab change output type to class library instead of Windows application.

Answer (score 4):

Console Application is an application (.exe), not a Library (.dll). To make a library, create a new project, select "Class Library" in type of project, then copy the logic of your first code into this new project.

Or you can edit the Project Properties and select Class Library instead of Console Application in *Output type*.

As some code can be "console" dependant, I think first solution is better if you check your logic when you copy it.

Answer (score -1):

[Creating DLL File](http://mauricemuteti.info/how-to-create-and-use-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-in-c-visual-studio-2010-step-by-step/)

1. Open Visual Studio then select `File` -> `New` -> `Project`
2. Select `Visual C#` -> `Class library`
3. Compile Project Or Build the solution, to create Dll File
4. Go to the class library folder (Debug Folder)